# Problema con la última ejecución de un while

Tags: java

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema, el programa está perfectamente pero cuando le doy el número 10 de alto, en vez de escribirme ******* me escribe una linea de ------

Lo ideal sería que escribiera una linea de asteriscos la última vez, no se me ocurren más formas.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Cristobal
 */
public class Ejercicio5_Try2 {

    public static int alto, ancho;
    public static String guiones = "-";
    public static String asteriscos ="*";
    public static String rectangulo, altorectangulo;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

do {

    try

    {
            System.out.println("Escribe el alto del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10");
            alto = sc.nextInt();
            int i = alto;

            System.out.println("Escribe el ancho del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10");
            ancho = sc.nextInt();








        while ((i>0) && (i<=10)){
            i--;

        rectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", guiones);
        System.out.println(rectangulo);

        if (i>1)
        {

        while (i>1){
        i--;
        altorectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", asteriscos);
        System.out.println(altorectangulo);
        break;

        }
        }

        }

    } 




    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Has introducido un valor incorrecto");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    } while ((alto <= 0) || (ancho <= 0) || (alto > 10) || (ancho > 10));

    }
}
```

EDIT:

Ejemplos de introducción de datos

```
run:
Escribe el alto del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
1
Escribe el ancho del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
5
-----
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)



run:
Escribe el alto del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
2
Escribe el ancho del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
8
--------
--------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)


run:
Escribe el alto del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
9
Escribe el ancho del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
10
----------
**********
----------
**********
----------
**********
----------
**********
----------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)


run:
Escribe el alto del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
10
Escribe el ancho del rectángulo, entre 0 y 10
10
----------
**********
----------
**********
----------
**********
----------
**********
----------
----------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el resultado por pantalla que obtienes? Leer el código sin indentación es un poco difícil.

Comment: Listo, ya están añadidos algunos ejemplos de ejecución, siendo el 10-10 el fallo que quiero corregir, para que la última línea fuera asteriscos

Comment: Por favor explica el objetivo de tu programa.

Comment: @CristobalRuiz El caso de 2 y 8 también tendría que acabar en asterisco?

Comment: @Edu3D Me he fijado que el 1 y 2 funcionaban bien, pero el 4 y cualquier número par daba fallo, con la respuesta de abajo me va perfecto.

Comment: Ya, te la iba a comentar, pero como decías que te funcionaba todo menos el caso 10/10 pues esperé tu respuesta xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sustituye las condiciones `if` del siguiente modo:

```
while ((i>0) && (i<=10)){
            i--;

        rectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", guiones);
        System.out.println(rectangulo);

        if (i>=1) //RETOQUE AQUÍ
        {

        while (i>=1){ //RETOQUE AQUÍ
        i--;
        altorectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", asteriscos);
        System.out.println(altorectangulo);
        break;

        }
        }

        }
```